# Python Pandas replace NaN rows with row with same dateindex from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which look something like this:

```
2001-01-03 00:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.95110  0.95110  0.95110  0.95110  4.0
2001-01-03 00:02:00  0.95100  0.95110  0.95100  0.95110  4.0
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.95100  0.95100  0.95100  0.95100  4.0
2001-01-03 00:04:00  0.95090  0.95090  0.95090  0.95090  4.0
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.95100  0.95100  0.95100  0.95100  4.0
```

What I'm trying to do is replace any NaN row in one df with the row of the same dateindex from another df.

I tried something like this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: df2.ix[x['row']] if x.isnull().any() else x)
```

But it just throws a bunch of errors, and probably wouldn't the most optimal method even if I could get it to work.
As I understand it may be possible to do it with .update(), but I haven't been able to get my head around it, so if anyone could offer some help I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: won't `df.fillna(df2)` work?

Comment: check method combine_first. `df.combine_first(df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.combine`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Or [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Or [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
```

But need same column names in both `DataFrames`.

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:03:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:02:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): np.nan, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:05:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:04:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 2: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:03:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:02:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): np.nan, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:05:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:04:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 3: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:03:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:02:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): np.nan, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:05:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:04:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 4: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:03:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:02:00'): 0.95109999999999995, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): np.nan, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:05:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:04:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 5: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 4.0, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:03:00'): 4.0, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:02:00'): 4.0, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): np.nan, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:05:00'): 4.0, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:04:00'): 4.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 2: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 3: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 4: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 0.95099999999999996, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): 0.95089999999999997}, 5: {pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:01:00'): 4.0, pd.Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): 4.0}})

print (df1)
                          1       2       3       4    5
2001-01-03 00:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:02:00  0.9510  0.9511  0.9510  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
2001-01-03 00:04:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0

print (df2)
                          1       2       3       4    5
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
```

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
                          1       2       3       4    5
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:02:00  0.9510  0.9511  0.9510  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
2001-01-03 00:04:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0

df = df1.fillna(df2)
print (df)
                          1       2       3       4    5
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:02:00  0.9510  0.9511  0.9510  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
2001-01-03 00:04:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0

df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
                          1       2       3       4    5
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:01:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
2001-01-03 00:02:00  0.9510  0.9511  0.9510  0.9511  4.0
2001-01-03 00:03:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
2001-01-03 00:04:00  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  0.9509  4.0
2001-01-03 00:05:00  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  0.9510  4.0
```

Comment: `df1.update(df2, overwrite=False)` - disable overwriting so that all methods give the same o/p?

Comment: @NickilMaveli - Thank you. Obviosly yes.